# Django: Bootstrap classes loading but not my style.css

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here is my HTML file:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Link to Bookstrap and stylesheet -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %'}"></script>

  </head>
  <body class="bg-blue">

    <div class="container">
      <div class ="row">
        <div class ="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <div class="panel panel-body">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase"><b> {% block heading %}{% endblock %}</b></h3>
              <br/>
              {% block content %}{% endblock %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to use the "bg-blue" class defined in my style.css.

```
.bg-blue{
  background-color: #3F3F63;
}
```

However it doesn't work. My boostrap and style.css are in the same folder. The Bootstrap loads, for example my text in centered and uppercase and the font is different.

I've also tried putting the class directly in the html file, and that works, but I want to be able to use style.css.

Edit: it works in Firefox but not Chrome, so it's not the code, any explain to this?

Comment: Try refreshing your cache in your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because you forgot to clear cache in chrome.press `control + F5` to clear cache and load again.